# Install interpreter for Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin, spark-notebook

I need to custom install interpreter for zeppelin apache. Not all of interpreter, i only need md, shell, python (default), jdbc, spark (default). I do some ways, but it failed:

1. Install online via command

   ./bin/install-interpreter.sh --name md,shell,jdbc

But i received error like this:

```
Install jdbc(org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-jdbc:0.8.0) to /opt/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-netinst/interpreter/jdbc ...
org.sonatype.aether.RepositoryException: Cannot fetch dependencies for org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-jdbc:0.8.0
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.getArtifactsWithDep(DependencyResolver.java:179)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.loadFromMvn(DependencyResolver.java:128)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:76)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:93)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:85)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:170)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:134)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:126)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.main(InstallInterpreter.java:278)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:352)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.getArtifactsWithDep(DependencyResolver.java:176)
        ... 8 more
```

I configed like this to fix it:
In zeppelin-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.interpreter.dep.mvnRepo</name>
  <value>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</value>
  <description>Remote principal repository for interpreter's additional dependency loading</description>
</property>
```

and in zeppelin-env.sh

```
export ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_DEP_MVNREPO="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IroiW.png)

i changed http to https, but it have no efffect.

2. Install offline
   I download jar file from mvnrepository and run

   bin/install-interpreter.sh --name md --artifact /tmp/zeppelin-jar/zeppelin-markdown-0.8.2.jar && 
   bin/install-interpreter.sh --name shell --artifact /tmp/zeppelin-jar/zeppelin-shell-0.8.2.jar && 
   bin/install-interpreter.sh --name jdbc --artifact /tmp/zeppelin-jar/zeppelin-jdbc-0.8.2.jar

But packages relate to many other dependencies jar need to download. Example:

```
zeppelin-shell-0.8.2 need some dependencies
org.apache.commons » commons-exec
org.apache.commons » commons-lang3
org.apache.zeppelin » zeppelin-interpreter  
org.slf4j » slf4j-api   
org.slf4j » slf4j-log4j12
```

How to install interpreter? I expected can install via command online. But seem error because network. I installed from my PC on company

Thank you every one so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded full version of zeppelin 0.9.0. Problem resolved